# Angular Firebasedatabase error Cannot read property 'databaseURL' of undefined

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i install firebase on angular 4  and i add it on app-module 
and in enviroment get config script also i changed i changed the authentically from rull to true

and in component i was import the AngularFireDatabase 
and write

app-module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFireModule} from 'angularfire2';
import {AngularFireDatabaseModule} from 'angularfire2/database';

import {environment} from '../environments/environment';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { UsersComponent } from './component/users/users.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UsersComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

enviromnet

```
export const environment = {
  production: false
  firecase:{
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCD3yDwF7qBcepnAXEspXbfchMtaGncHtg",
    authDomain: "courses-4d546.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://courses-4d546.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "courses-4d546",
    storageBucket: "courses-4d546.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "760508178350"
  }

};
```

component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {

  courses: any[];

constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
  db.list('/courses')
    .subscribe(courses =>{
    this.courses=courses;
    console.log(this.courses);
  })
}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**i have Error** 
Cannot read property 'databaseURL' of undefined[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
AppComponent.html:2 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'databaseURL' of undefined
    at RepoManager.databaseFromApp (index.cjs.js:14981)
    at Object.instance.INTERNAL.registerService.Reference [as database] (index.cjs.js:15328)
    at FirebaseAppImpl._getService (index.cjs.js:134)
    at FirebaseAppImpl.(:4200/anonymous function) [as database] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/app/dist/index.cjs.js:323:31)
    at eval (database.js:11)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:138)
    at NgZone.runOutsideAngular (core.js:4708)
    at new AngularFireDatabase (database.js:9)
    at _createClass (core.js:10943)
```

Comment: can you post the error stacktrace as text and not image please

Comment: ok thank you  - 1 sec

Comment: you need to do `valueChanges()` or `snapshotChanges()` before subscribe.. I am not entirely sure that is the cause..unless you are using an old version of angularfire2

Comment: i use firebase2 and version of angular4

Comment: You haven't included any of the actual important files in your repo, so it's very difficult to help. For instance, where is your index.html? Where are you initializing firebase? How have you imported AngularFire? Where is your app.module? Where is your package.json?

Comment: i just miss files when i uploaded on github , i explain more my question thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same issue today and resolved in one way. You placed firebase configuration in `environment.ts` file. Instead of that place this data in `app.module.ts` like this.

```
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
 import {AngularFireModule} from 'angularfire2';
 import {AngularFireDatabaseModule} from 'angularfire2/database';

 import {environment} from '../environments/environment';
 import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
 import { UsersComponent } from './component/users/users.component';

 export const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCD3yDwF7qBcepnAXEspXbfchMtaGncHtg",
    authDomain: "courses-4d546.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://courses-4d546.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "courses-4d546",
    storageBucket: "courses-4d546.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "760508178350"
 }

 @NgModule({
   declarations: [
     AppComponent,
     UsersComponent
   ],
   imports: [
     BrowserModule,
     AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
     AngularFireDatabaseModule
   ],
   providers: [],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
 })
 export class AppModule { }
```

This works, but I don't know the exact way to resolve `databaseURL` error.

Answer (score 4):

in your file app-module you call this

```
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
```

so you need to make it **firebase** instead of **firecase** in environment
so your environment must be look like

```
export const environment = {
     production: false
     firebase:{
        apiKey: "AIzaSyCD3yDwF7qBcepnAXEspXbfchMtaGncHtg",
        authDomain: "courses-4d546.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://courses-4d546.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "courses-4d546",
        storageBucket: "courses-4d546.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "760508178350"
     }

};
```

Comment: i add to you i foreget put observable in component

Answer (score 0):

The error message would imply that firebase has not been initialized with a config object (which contains the `databaseUrl`).

Are you sure that you are calling `firebase.initializeApp` as described in the [web setup docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup)?

Comment: yes i initialize it    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),

Comment: inside import [] app-modal file

Comment: Are you certain that `initializeApp` is being called *before* `db.list`? Try setting a breakpoint in both places and start your app.